# exercise with bash shell and ls command

Tags: bash, shell

I have to create a shell script that: counts the number of files that have this extension; calculate total file size with this extension; list to the user the names of the (extension-free) les whose size is greater than 1000 bytes; ask the user for confirmation for the removal of larger files; delete all files if the user replies in the affirmative. I did this but it doesn't work for me because it doesn't look for the extension typed by the user with awk.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"
do

   echo "I file con estensione $file sono:"
   ls -l | awk '/$file/ {print $9}' | wc -l


   a=$(ls -l | awk '/$file/ {somma+=$5} END {print somma}')
   echo "La dimensione di tali file in totale e':$a"

   echo "I file con estensione pdf che hanno dimensione maggiore di 1000 sono: "
   ls -l|awk ' /$file/ && $5>1000 {print $9}'

   echo "Vuoi cancellarli : 
   1) Si 
   2) No 
   Digita scelta : "
   read answer
   case $answer in
   Si)
         if ls -l | awk '/$file/ && $5>1000 {print $9}' | sed '/$file/d'
         then
            echo "I file cancellati sono: "
         fi
      ;;
   No)
      echo "Non cancellati"
      ;;
 *) 
 esac
done
```

Can you tell me what's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Using the output of `ls` is a `no-go.`

Comment: @Cyrus the exercise dictates it

Answer (score 0):

Um, which extension? I don't see in the script anything about extension.
It's probably should be like this:

```
ls -l *.$extension | ...
```

And `$file` variable won't expand inside`''` you should use `""` or better pass vars into `awk` like this:

```
awk -vfile="$file" '{...}'
```

Comment: so like this : for extension in "$@"
do

    echo "Files with the $extension extension are:"
    ls -l *.$extension | awk /$file/ {print $9}' | wc -l
  done

Comment: No `awk` is not bash. It has different syntax. Try `ls -l *.$extension | awk -v file="$file" '$0 ~ file {print $9}'`.

Comment: @saretta2 yes but `$file` variable must be wrapped with `""` or passed through `-v` option of `awk`. It won't work inside `''`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws in your script.  Let me try a partial list:

- **Bash quoting**.  Bash distinguishes between double and single quotes.  Within single quotes, variables are not expanded.
- **ls option**.  You can use -1 to force one file per line.  It is cheaper than ls -l.
- **ls vs bash**.  Contest the mandate to use ls.  You can get the list of files without it, and the size using stat.  For example:

```bash
for ext in "$@"
do
    for file in *.$ext
    do
        size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
        #...
    done
done
```

- **Mind regex**.  Say you're looking for .mov files and have a file named my-movies.txt.  Your awk expression matches it too.
- **Use variables**.  A file could be added between the script asking and the user replying.  A better approach is to hold the files in a local variable.
- **sed vs rm**.  The sed line editor deletes input lines, not files from disk.  I understand this still formally satisfies the exercise...

Comment: okay using rm to remove files like i should do, so rm $file ?